# run multiple OLS in a dataframe for unique ID in pandas and put results of each unique ID in descriptive table

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a dataset which talks about firms' financial information from 1987 to 1999 with different industries. Now I wanna run an OLS for each industries. There are 137 industries in the dataframe with 28128 firms-year available. `df['Industry']` is the code for each industry, same code means the same industry. After getting the intercept and coefs of each industry, put them in to a statistic descriptive table.

I am thinking of writing a for loop but have no idea how.
first I filter out industries that have at least 50 observations

```
Dechow_1987 = Dechow_1987[Dechow_1987.groupby('Industry')['Industry'].transform('size') >= 50]
    print( 'Firm-years available:' ,Dechow_1987.shape[0])
    print( 'Number of Industries available:' , Dechow_1987.Industry.nunique())
```

And I want to get this table at the end:

```
               Intercept  b1    b     b3     Adjusted R2
 Mean            0.03    0.19   -0.51   0.15     0.34
 (t-statistic) (16.09) (21.10) (-35.77) (15.33)
 Lower quartile 0.01     0.11   -0.63    0.08    0.22
 Median         0.03     0.18    -0.52    0.15    0.34
 Upper quartile 0.04     0.26    -0.40    0.23      0.4
```

I have tried :

```
ind = Dechow_1987.Industry.unique()

op=pd.DataFrame()
for i in ind:
    
    Dechow_1987_i = Dechow_1987[Dechow_1987.Industry == i]
    X_CFOs = Dechow_1987_i[['CFOtm1', 'CFOt', 'CFOtp1']]
    X_CFOs = sm.add_constant(X_CFOs)
    Y_WC= Dechow_1987_i['wcch']
    reg = sm.OLS(Y_WC, X_CFOs).fit()
    #reg.score(Y_WC,X_CFOs)
    intercept = reg.params.const
    coef_CFOtm1 = reg.params.CFOtm1
    coef_CFOt = reg.params.CFOt
    coef_CFOtp1 = reg.params.CFOtp1

    ind=i
    array=np.append(coef_CFOtm1,coef_CFOt,coef_CFOtp1).dtype('int32')
    array=np.append(array,intercept)
    array=np.append(array,ind)
    array=array.reshape(3,len(array))
    df_append=pd.DataFrame(array)
    op=op.append(df_append)

op.columns=['A'+str(i) for i in range (3,len(op.columns)+1)]
op.rename(columns={op.columns[-1]:"Industry"},inplace=True)
op.rename(columns={op.columns[-2]:"Intercept"},inplace=True)
op=op.reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
op=op.drop_duplicates()
```

It come out :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-60ce6bb71209> in <module>
     18 
     19     ind=i
---> 20     array=np.append(coef_CFOtm1,coef_CFOt,coef_CFOtp1).dtype('int32')
     21     array=np.append(array,intercept)
     22     array=np.append(array,ind)

<__array_function__ internals> in append(*args, **kwargs)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in append(arr, values, axis)
   4743         values = ravel(values)
   4744         axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4745     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
   4746 
   4747 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

   

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste data directly in the question and format as code, posting images doesn't help. Also, please specify what you have tried so far

Comment: You iterate over `ind` - `for i in ind:` - and in the loop you set `ind=i`. That doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do here `array=np.append(coef_CFOtm1,coef_CFOt,coef_CFOtp1).dtype('int32')` with `.dtype('int32')`? Also: Have you checked the signature of `np.append`: I doubt this `np.append(coef_CFOtm1,coef_CFOt,coef_CFOtp1)` will work?